# Could This Method Create a Zombie Apocalypse

Tags: magic, apocalypse

Background: Let's say a "failed" (they thought it failed, at least) government experiment created a portal that a necromancer existed from. The necromancer has the following abilities:

1. He can leech lifeforce from creatures he is in contact with. Organic clothing won't protect from this (like a leather jacket), but synthetic ones will. He can also infect (turn undead) someone he's touching, and this will work through organic clothing.
2. He can turn to an infectious slime, think a giant slime mold, but faster and stronger, capable of turning doorknobs and overtaking a jogging (NOT running) human. This slime is unaffected by direct and even harsh sunlight, not so much light focused enough to function as a firestarter. Obviously, he can switch between humans and slime form.
3. He can form and fire spores from his body, especially in slime form. Alternatively, he can plant a mushroom underneath him or where a selected pseudopod lands. This mushroom will fire spores at nearby (living) creatures.
4. Upon contacting a creature in slime form, the necromancer can infect them, seeping into their body. Clothes and body armor offer varying degrees of protection-of course he can go through silk and denim, but a raincoat? Not so much. If his spores hit the skin or non-synthetic clothing, they will convert to energy and hit the nearest nerves, racing through the entire nervous system in a mere five seconds. At that point, the necromancer will control the new undead.
5. The necromancer turns to slime whenever he dies, and if part of him is cut off, that part of him turns to slime. He can survive having his head cut off, and his head-slime can still direct the body using the sensory information it receives. He can turn parts of him back to flesh and bone to regain lost body parts. His one weakness is *fire*-burning his slime will reduce it to ashes and release the spirit within. That leaves him as a ghost, which can only bother the living world through telepathy, *unless* he succeeds in convincing or fooling someone into a ritual that turns them into his next host.

Finally, these zombies can infect someone by touching someone with their fungus-infused body (contact) or by forming and throwing a "spore", or glob of fungus-infused flesh.

Could this necromancer successfully cause the zombie apocalypse?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Can the zombies made by your necromancer spread their infection to other zombies?

Comment: Yes, actually. I will add that to the question information.

Comment: Answer: yes. The necromancer is fully equipped to do that. However, *will he*? That's actually up to your story.

Comment: Yes, he is equipped to do that. However, determining whether he succeeds is a different story. One has to account for intelligence agencies, the military, and politicians to figure that out, which is why I posted this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Better Question: Could Anyone Stop Him?

TLDR: no

This guy can create zombies that he has rudimentary control over.  Even if it's as limited as him only being able to point them in a direction, this removes the primary limitation of zombies as they now have a strategic planner directing their movements instead of always wandering around aimlessly.  The common man can't stand up to that.

He can create zombie-making mines.  The value of this ability to initiate the plague cannot be overstated.  He can walk through city alleys and plant them in obscure places and they will either catch people before they even know to be afraid of strange mushrooms or when they are too busy running from zombies to pay attention to their surroundings.  Initiating an outbreak in any major city is trivial with this ability, and he could possibly set up an outbreak in the middle of the night, and then leave the city before rush hour traffic starts.

His only weakness is fire.  I don't know if you've noticed, but humans have spent decades trying to eliminate open flames where they can be wildely flailed about as a weapon. It's possible that certain firearms will react with his slime in the same way as fire, but I don't expect he'll instantly catch on fire and burn to ash.  More likely, he'll just actually feel it and be unable to regenerate that part of him for a while.

He can seemlessly integrate himself into any group of friendly survivors while in necromancer form.  Sure, a lot of people will be distrusting of strangers, but a lot of other people will just insit on inspecting you for bites before saying that traveling in a group is safer.  He can easily show that he's not been bitten, and then he's a fully trustworthy human just like them.  Even groups that don't trust him are unlikely to murder him on sight, which would let him plant some mushrooms around them when they aren't watching him.

The military and intelligence agencies are useless against him.  He is a single man that is so far off the grid that modern intelligence practices could never hope to find him.  They might be able to track or even predict his path by recording the spread of infections from city to city, but that's assuming the vast majority of their infrastructure doesn't crumble as disaster response measures fail to stand up to the plague.

He can travel anywhere in the world by boat to continue the spread of the zombies.  He'll be picked up by border patrol, and then he'll just claim to be a refugee fleeing the zombies.  Human prisons need to have ventalation, so his slime form cannot be contained in a prison designed to hold humans.  Odds are very good that he'll be taken to a refugee camp because he probably won't be the first person to reach the country fleeing the zombies. He can then infect the refugee camp, and no one will question it because of course a camp full of refugees from a zombie infected locality will have some people with delayed responses to the zombie outbreak.

And let's say that someone manages to kill him and burn his body.  Great! Now he's an immortal ghost with all the time in the world to find some mentally unstable person that he can convince to bring him back, and this time he'll have even more knowledge of the way the world works (presuming it works at all by this time).

I think at this point, it's fair to say:

**Nec OP, plz nerf.**

Comment: What I'm probably going to do is set up a rival necromancer or zombie plague, or maybe an immune hero/heroine. Sure, I could nerf him, but it's more fun to have nigh-invincible villains!

Comment: Upvoted because I did not foresee the possibility of zombie-making mimes!  I am super enthusiastic about that because otherwise this whole scenario seemed kind of tired.  Nothing wrong with it, you know but it seems like you could huck some molotov cocktails at this dude and be done with it.   Maybe I just want mimes included in everything, the way I want cheese and hot sauce included in everything.  It may be something to do with my upbringing.